# Move window to desktop: Keyboard shortcut

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running Linux Mint 17.1 (KDE). I know that I'm able to move windows from one desktop space to another by right-clicking in the title bar. I also know I'm able to do so from the command line with wmctrl, which first requires me to know the window ID. In my case, I can do this:

```
wmctrl -l
```

This lists open windows with their respective IDs:

> 0x04c00012  0 laptop2 Downloads – Dolphin
>
> 0x00800015 -1 laptop2 Yakuake
>
> 0x03800012  1 laptop2 sh-format.sh – Kate

(along with several others).

If I then type:

```
wmctrl -i -r 0x03800012 -t 1
```

then I can move the Kate window to desktop 2.

**My question is this:**
I would like to either (1) set up a keyboard shortcut to move the active window to a different desktop (I'm willing to set up separate shortcuts per desktop), or (2) identify the window ID for the active window, so that I can script a shortcut.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can just do this with the builtin KWin scripts? In Plasma 5, you can set the key at System Settings > (Workspace) Shortcuts > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KWin > Window to Desktop 2.

Comment: @Sparhawk: I thought I should be able to, but don't have this option in KWin. I'm confused by this, but so it is.

Comment: It might be different in KDE 4 (is that what Mint ships with?), but [this](http://i.imgur.com/l4Q3D5h.png) is how it looks in Plasma 5. I definitely used that option in KDE 4, at least in Arch Linux and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution. Rather than delete the question, I thought I'd post what I have. I'm sure someone or other has the same question somewhere, and if not, I'm sure there's still a cleaner way of doing this. Here goes.

(This, by the way, is to make a keyboard shortcut to move the active window to workspace 4.)

First, I wrote a script (~/.move4.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev`;wmctrl -i -r $a -t 3
```

(the "-t 3" is because the workspace numbering starts at zero, so "-t 3" moves the window to workspace 4)

I made the script executable:

```
chmod u+x ~/.move4.sh
```

Finally, I went into system settings and made a custom global keyboard shortcut (I used Meta+4), and assigned it to run this script. Worked like a charm.

I feel silly for not having come up with it sooner, but I think I had to post a question to come up with an answer. Sorry.

Comment: You could just use:

`wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -t 3` (assuming you want to send to the 4th desktop)

Instead of `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev` I would recommend `xdotool getactivewindow`